# Simplest method to determine if the current time is AM or PM?

Tags: vb.net, datetime

What is the best method to determine if the current time is AM or PM using VB.NET?

Currently I'm using If Date.Today.ToString.Contains("AM") but I'm sure there is a better method.

```
Good <%If Date.Today.ToString.Contains("AM") Then Response.Write("Morning") Else Response.Write("Afternoon")%>
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`If Date.Now.Hour < 12 Then` ... perhaps?

Comment: Does Date.Now.Hour always return 0-23, or could it ever return 1-12?

Comment: It will always return 0-23. Displaying it, thus converting it to a string, might show 0-11/12, etc. but that's a localization/display issue. The Time property will always be 00:00:00 - 23:59:59 (+ milliseconds etc.)

Comment: See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.hour.aspx In the remarks it says this: The value of the Hour property is always expressed using a 24-hour clock.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a way to do this without if statements, that way something like 
`msgbox(now.hour.12hr & ":" & now.minute & " " & now.AMPM)`

maybe not using `now` though since most of this doesn't exist.
It just seems like displaying the time in a standard US format should be easier.

Comment: Sure, use the format string "hh:mm:ss tt" and you'll get 12-hour clock and tt = am/pm. Note that you need to do this in a culture which uses this kind of format, otherwise they would probably want to see a 24-hour clock. Note that if you just use the format string "t" or "T" to get time + am/pm, T also gives you seconds. This format will also be culture-sensitive and display 24-hour without am/pm if the current culture doesn't use am/pm.

Comment: See [DateTime.ToString Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx) for more information

Answer (score 4):

```
Now.ToString("t") == "A" //or //"P"
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
Now.Hour > 17 ' Night
Now.Hour < 5  ' Day
```

HTH

Answer (score 2):

The afternoon check needs to be <= otherwise at hour 17 str nevers gets set

```
dim hours as int = DateTime.Now.Hour
dim str as string
if hours < 12 Then
    str = "Morning"
else if hours <= 17 then
    str = "Afternoon"
else if hours > 17 then
    str = "Evening"
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
dim hours as int = DateTime.Now.Hour
dim str as string
if hours < 12 Then
    str = "Morning"
else if hours < 17 then
    str = "Afternoon"
else if hours > 17 then
    str = "Evening"
End If
```

Comment: And hours = 17 then str = "tea time"

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Function IsMidnight(ByVal value As DateTime) As Boolean
    Return value.Hour = 0 And _
        value.Minute = 0 And _
        value.Second = 0 And _
        value.Millisecond = 0
End Function
```

Usage:

```
Dim isAM as Boolean = (IsMidnight(current) Or current.Hour < 12)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim dateValue = Dtp.Value.ToString()
If dateValue.EndsWith("AM") Then
   MsgBox("Its AM")
Else
   MsgBox("Its PM")
End If
```

You can do something like this.